# MaxMind GeoIP City State accuracy

Tags: geoip, maxmind

Are the MaxMind .dat IPs of locations of the registered IP City/State, or really the location of the IP address? For example some frontier networks that are hitting Chicago 74.40.5.109 are showing the city/st of Bellevue, WA. 
I am trying to use your service for trace route research, but want to make sure the results are accurate.
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/14591/tracert-map-view-the-ip-network-path-on-a-map

Is there a difference in the different GeoIP options that are more accurate for city/state?

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are 3 types of geolocation technology in the industry right now.

1. IP Geolocation
   It detects location based on IP address. Due to the frequent reallocation of IP address, it has less accuracy.
2. Wifi MAC or Base Station Geolocation
   It detects location based on WIFI router MAC address or mobile base station ID collected from phone. It has more accuracy compare to IP address because the location of these stations are fixed.
3. GPS
   It detects location based on 3 GPS satellites. It is highly accurate with accuracy less than 10m. You will need to have a device with GPS receiver in order to get this information.

Reference: https://www.geolocation.com